# C# execut a function created from string

Tags: c#, string, unity-game-engine, methods

I'm trying to make like a small interpreter from some scripting language to C# and I need to execute a C# method which is written in a string variable and I want to execute that. Is that possible? And if yes... how exactly can I do this?

My functions function on the end will look something like this:

```
 public IEnumerator Blink()
    {
        TurnOnLed(true);
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(2);
        for (var i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
        {
            TurnOnLed(false);
            yield return new WaitForSeconds(1);
            TurnOnLed(true);
            yield return new WaitForSeconds(1);
        }
    }
```

Script code:

```
output(true)
sleep(2)
for x in range(10)
    output(false)
    sleep(1)
    output(true)
    sleep(1)
```

Where WaitForSeconds is a Unity3D function and TurnOnLed(true) it's mine.
when I seach on internet I've fond some solutions where I will create an entire class to be able to run this methon... is any other solution?

Is it there any easy way to do this?

Comment: What does your scripting language parser look like?

Comment: @FelixGuo I've add this on question, it's kind of Python

Comment: Maybe this will help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4181668/execute-c-sharp-code-at-runtime-from-code-file

Answer (score 1):

You really have to create complete classes to be able to run resulting C# code. You can always wrap code fragment into class with single method to construct a working class and than compile it (compiling covered in [Is it possible to dynamically compile and execute C# code fragments?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/826398/is-it-possible-to-dynamically-compile-and-execute-c-sharp-code-fragments) )

```
var myCode = "Console.WriteLine(\"!!!\")";
var classFormat = "class Fake{0} {{ public void Do(){{ {1} ;}} }}";
var finalCode = String.Format(classFormat, 123, myCode);
```

---

It sounds like you actually want to build code to run rather than transcode your script into C#, than compile C# into IL and than execute IL. Instead you can directly generate IL or construct [`Expression`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.expressions.expression(v=vs.110).aspx) tree - starting points [Reflection.Emit vs CodeDOM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2366921/reflection-emit-vs-codedom). Based on your script sample and requirement to not create complete classes `Expression` tree would be better option.

---

Another option is to use existing scripting engines - Lua, JavaScript, Python and many other have parsers that allow you to execute scripts from .Net code (i.e. [How can I call (Iron)Python code from a C# app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7053172/how-can-i-call-ironpython-code-from-a-c-sharp-app))

Answer (score 0):

Given that you're using Unity, there's a cheap and slightly hacky way to do this: The built-in Unity function **GameObject.SendMessage()** allows you to invoke C# functions using the function name string. Here's the relevant code from the Unity docs:

```
public class ExampleClass : MonoBehaviour {

    void ApplyDamage(float damage) {
        print(damage);
    }

    void Example() {
        gameObject.SendMessage("ApplyDamage", 5.0F);
    }

}
```

Hope this helps.