# How to use incompleted types in reflection?

Tags: c#, reflection, system.reflection

I want to dynamically generate the assembly, which can have functions with different structures. To be more accurate, these functions can be recursive, they can call other functions within the same assembly etc. I found the `System.Reflection` module which theoretically provides tools to do this, but in practice I have encountered many drawbacks for this approach. For example - I cannot generate recursive functions via `TypeBuilder` and `MethodBuilder` classes, because exception will be thrown (usage of incomplete types). I learned that I can generate selfrecursive functions via `IlGenerator` - but it is too cumbersome - I hoped that there is an easier way to do this.

Here is my program which demonstrates the problem (at generation of method `Fact` the following Exception is thrown:

> ```
> Exception thrown: 'System.NotSupportedException' in mscorlib.dll 
> Additional information: Specified method is not supported..
> ```

**Code**:

```
using System;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Reflection.Emit;
using System.Linq.Expressions;

namespace GenericFuncs
{
    public class ProgramBuilder
    {
        public Type createMyProgram()
        {
            var assmName = new AssemblyName("DynamicAssemblyExample");
            var assmBuilder = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.DefineDynamicAssembly(assmName, AssemblyBuilderAccess.RunAndSave);
            var moduleBuilder = assmBuilder.DefineDynamicModule(assmName.Name, assmName.Name + ".dll");
            var myProgramType = buildMyProgram(moduleBuilder, moduleBuilder.DefineType("MyProgram", TypeAttributes.Public));
            assmBuilder.Save(assmName.Name + ".dll");
            return myProgramType;
        }        

        private Type buildMyProgram(ModuleBuilder mb, TypeBuilder programBuilder)
        {
            buildFactFunction2(mb, mb.GetType("MyProgram"), programBuilder.DefineMethod("InfLoop", MethodAttributes.Public | MethodAttributes.Static));
            buildFactFunction(mb, mb.GetType("MyProgram"), programBuilder.DefineMethod("Fact", MethodAttributes.Public | MethodAttributes.Static));
            return programBuilder.CreateType();
        }

        private void buildFactFunction(ModuleBuilder mb, Type program_type, MethodBuilder methodBuilder)
        {
            var param = Expression.Parameter(typeof(int), "n");
            var lambda = Expression.Lambda(Expression.Call(methodBuilder, param), param);
            lambda.CompileToMethod(methodBuilder);
        }

        static public void my_print(string s)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(s);
        }

        private void buildFactFunction2(ModuleBuilder mb, Type program_type, MethodBuilder methodBuilder)
        {
            var il = methodBuilder.GetILGenerator();
            il.Emit(OpCodes.Ldstr, "a");
            il.Emit(OpCodes.Call, typeof(ProgramBuilder).GetMethod("my_print"));
            il.Emit(OpCodes.Call, methodBuilder);
            il.Emit(OpCodes.Ret);
        }
    }

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var pbuilder = new ProgramBuilder();
            var ptype = pbuilder.createMyProgram();
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

[Expressions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/statements-expressions-operators/expressions) and reflection in C# have their limitations (albeit still very powerful for simple use cases). To the best of my knowledge, [Emit](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.emit(v=vs.110).aspx) is the way to go if you need the functionality which you describe (even the basic requirement of emitting assemblies).

Some years ago, I used [RunSharp](https://code.google.com/archive/p/runsharp/) quite effectively in some minimal dynamic code generation use cases. It takes away most of the IL pains. For example, in [this code](https://github.com/Whathecode/Framework-Class-Library-Extension/blob/master/Whathecode.System/Reflection/Emit/Proxy.cs) I create a proxy wrapper at runtime.

You could also have a look at what [Castle Project](http://www.castleproject.org/) uses for their code generation, e.g., their [DynamicProxy](http://www.castleproject.org/projects/dynamicproxy/) is quite popular.

Comment: thanks for reply. I will check it out, but it seems like RunSharp project is dead (And I am not sure that it is pretty stable library). (maybe Castle Project helps somehow)

Comment: @LmTinyToon It gives you a starting point to know what to Google for I hope. :) For example, I hadn't heard of [Happil](http://felix-b.github.io/Hapil/) before which shows up now when looking for similar libraries. I guess the key take-away message is that you will need to use Emit (and preferably you can find the latest stable wrapper library to help you with it).

Answer (score 3):

This is probably not what you are after but have you thought about *CodeDom* ?

The downside is it wont be truly dynamic, as you have to load the assembly

[Dynamic Source Code Generation and Compilation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/reflection-and-codedom/dynamic-source-code-generation-and-compilation)

As pointed out by *Steven Jeuris* There is a great question on the differences between *CodeDom* and *Emit* [Reflection.Emit vs CodeDOM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2366921/reflection-emit-vs-codedom)

> - CodeDom generates C# source code and is usually used when generating code to be included as part of a solution and compiled in the IDE (for
>     example, LINQ to SQL classes, WSDL, XSD all work this way). In this
>     scenario you can also use partial classes to customize the generated
>     code. It is less efficient, because it generates C# source and then
>     runs the compiler to parse it (again!) and compile it. You can
>     generate code using relatively high-level constructs (similar to C#
>     expressions & statements) such as loops.
> - Reflection.Emit generates an IL so it directly produces an assembly that can be also stored only in memory. As a result is a lot more
>     efficient.You have to generate low-level IL code (values are stored on
>     stack; looping has to be implemented using jumps), so generating any
>     more complicated logic is a bit difficult.

**Simple CodeDom Exmaple from MSDN**

```
public Sample()
{
    targetUnit = new CodeCompileUnit();
    CodeNamespace samples = new CodeNamespace("CodeDOMSample");
    samples.Imports.Add(new CodeNamespaceImport("System"));
    targetClass = new CodeTypeDeclaration("CodeDOMCreatedClass");
    targetClass.IsClass = true;
    targetClass.TypeAttributes =
        TypeAttributes.Public | TypeAttributes.Sealed;
    samples.Types.Add(targetClass);
    targetUnit.Namespaces.Add(samples);
}

public void AddFields()
{
    // Declare the widthValue field.
    CodeMemberField widthValueField = new CodeMemberField();
    widthValueField.Attributes = MemberAttributes.Private;
    widthValueField.Name = "widthValue";
    widthValueField.Type = new CodeTypeReference(typeof(System.Double));
    widthValueField.Comments.Add(new CodeCommentStatement(
        "The width of the object."));
    targetClass.Members.Add(widthValueField);

    // Declare the heightValue field
    CodeMemberField heightValueField = new CodeMemberField();
    heightValueField.Attributes = MemberAttributes.Private;
    heightValueField.Name = "heightValue";
    heightValueField.Type =
        new CodeTypeReference(typeof(System.Double));
    heightValueField.Comments.Add(new CodeCommentStatement(
        "The height of the object."));
    targetClass.Members.Add(heightValueField);
}

public void GenerateCSharpCode(string fileName)
{
    CodeDomProvider provider = CodeDomProvider.CreateProvider("CSharp");
    CodeGeneratorOptions options = new CodeGeneratorOptions();
    options.BracingStyle = "C";
    using (StreamWriter sourceWriter = new StreamWriter(fileName))
    {
        provider.GenerateCodeFromCompileUnit(
            targetUnit, sourceWriter, options);
    }
}

static void Main()
{
    Sample sample = new Sample();
    sample.AddFields();
    //sample.AddProperties();
    //sample.AddMethod();
    //sample.AddConstructor();
    //sample.AddEntryPoint();
    sample.GenerateCSharpCode(outputFileName);
}
```

And you could use one of several methods to run your code

```
 private static Assembly CompileSourceCodeDom(string sourceCode)
 {
     CodeDomProvider cpd = new CSharpCodeProvider();
     var cp = new CompilerParameters();
     cp.ReferencedAssemblies.Add("System.dll");
     cp.GenerateExecutable = false;
     CompilerResults cr = cpd.CompileAssemblyFromSource(cp, sourceCode);

     return cr.CompiledAssembly;
}

private static void ExecuteFromAssembly(Assembly assembly)
{
    Type fooType = assembly.GetType("Foo");
    MethodInfo printMethod = fooType.GetMethod("Print");
    object foo = assembly.CreateInstance("Foo");
    printMethod.Invoke(foo, BindingFlags.InvokeMethod, null, null, CultureInfo.CurrentCulture);
}
```

Comment: Right! I forgot about CodeDom. There is [this interesting question comparing CodeDom and Emit](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2366921/590790).

Comment: @StevenJeuris thanks, i plugged you, and upvoted your answers as well